# Xamarin app crash after installing a nuget package

Tags: xamarin, crash, package, nuget, sqlite-net-pcl

In visual studio 2017 I have created a Xamarin PCL project and the app works fine but after installing a nuget package called sqlite-net-pcl it crashes at startup.
I have tried installing other versions of it and tried changing build to 259 from 111 and still no luck.

Comment: What's the error? See debugging logs and describe exception

Comment: So I could not get sqlite-net-pcl to work but I found another package called SQLite.NET PCL and it worked just fine. It think sqlite-net-pcl just does not work with the current version of other packages I have because I am following a tutorial and did the exact same things but the app kept crashing so SQLite.NET PCL  so SQLite.NET PCL  worked fine.